# Angular 8 spinner or loader using unrelated components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Here is my code below **StaffMembers.ts** component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StaffService } from '../_services/Staff.service';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'StaffMembers',
  templateUrl: './StaffMembers.html'
})

export class StaffMembers implements OnInit {
  public StaffArr: Array<any>;
  constructor(private _StaffService: StaffService, private _router: Router) {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.StaffArr = await this._StaffService.GetStaff();
  }
}
```

Here is my **Staff.service.ts** service component below.

```
import { Injectable, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { HostedPathConst } from '../_helpers/path';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StaffService {
  private messageStaffSource: BehaviorSubject<Staff>;
  public currentStaffMessage: Observable<Staff>;
  private _Staff: Staff;
  private ProfileFile: FileList;
  private sL: Array<Staff> = new Array();


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private toastr: ToastrService) {
    this.messageStaffSource = new BehaviorSubject<Staff>(new Staff());
    this.currentStaffMessage = this.messageStaffSource.asObservable();
  }

  GetStaff(): Promise<any> {
    const promise = this.http.get(HostedPathConst.HostedPath + `Staff/GetStaff`).toPromise();
    return promise;
  }

  Error(data) {
  }
  Success(data) {
    this.toastr.success(data.errorMessage, 'Success !');
  }
}
```

Now as i want to add my loader on the page i have found a package from this URL which is working as expected.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tusharghoshbd/ngx-loader

As i use it in any HTML page its called by this way.

```
<ngx-loader [show]="show" [fullScreen] = "fullScreen" [template]="template"> Loading... </ngx-loader>
```

and in any component file its called like this way.

```
  //Declaration
  show = false;
  fullScreen = true;
  template = ``
   //Initialization
  this.show = true;
  this.fullScreen = true;
  this.template = ``;
  //And to stop the loader
  this.show = false
```

Now as i have above `two unrelated components` **StaffMembers.ts** for html component and for service **Staff.service.ts** now as i want to use the **spinner or loader** when the data is being fetched from the

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.StaffArr = await this._StaffService.GetStaff();
  }
```

How can i wait for my data being loaded to start and stop the **loader or spinner**.

Comment: don't fetch in `ngOnInit` try in later events like `ngAfterContentInit` and show before GetStaff and hide after it

Comment: `ngOnInit` generally is fine. Since you are using the async variant, setting show to true after the `await` should work. Otherwise change to using subscribe and set to false in there.

Comment: also consider using `ngprogress`, that's alot more popular and well documented than the package you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep them separated (and you should) I would use an http interceptor.

There is an excellent example on medium: https://medium.com/swlh/angular-loading-spinner-using-http-interceptor-63c1bb76517b

Check the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, map} from 'rxjs/operators'
import {LoadingService} from '../../layout/services/loading/loading.service';

/**
 * This class is for intercepting http requests. When a request starts, we set the loadingSub property
 * in the LoadingService to true. Once the request completes and we have a response, set the loadingSub
 * property to false. If an error occurs while servicing the request, set the loadingSub property to false.
 * @class {HttpRequestInterceptor}
 */
@Injectable()
export class HttpRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private _loading: LoadingService
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this._loading.setLoading(true, request.url);
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(catchError((err) => {
        this._loading.setLoading(false, request.url);
        return err;
      }))
      .pipe(map<HttpEvent<any>, any>((evt: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this._loading.setLoading(false, request.url);
        }
        return evt;
      }));
  }
}
```

In this example, the author uses a service to share change in state. You could use events too, but it would be trickier as it's out of the running scope of angular

Comment: can't he just use `this.show = true` and `this.show = false` before and after of : `this.StaffArr = await this._StaffService.GetStaff();` ?

Comment: My guess is that the loader is not in the component template file. It's declared on another template and needs to be used by all http calls.

Comment: I think in the case of question, `this.show = true` is enough. but as the application grows, there will be a need for solution like this. so catch my upvote.